# NavHostFragment not accessible from XML

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I wanted to try new Navigation library. After following [this guideline](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) I experienced error at runtime:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

in resource file `activity_home.xml`. This file is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_host"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_home" />

</FrameLayout>
```

I looked at the source code of `NavHostFragment` and I noticed that it uses `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` while whole my application uses `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`.

I'm not convinced that this is the issue, but I'm including some of my dependencies below:

```
// AndroidX
implementation     "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appCompatVersion"
implementation     "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintLayoutVersion"
implementation     "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion"
implementation     "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerViewVersion"
implementation     "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion"
implementation     "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion"

kapt               "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"

// Navigation
implementation     "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$navigationVersion"
implementation     "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$navigationVersion"
```

As you can see I'm using libraries from AndroidX except Navigation, because probably it's not migrated yet. The only place on Google where I can find `androidx.navigation` is [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started). Unfortunately Gradle is unable to download it.

**Edit**

I also have jetifier tool enabled inside my `gradle.properties`.

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

**Update**

It is fixed in Android Studio 3.2 Canary 17 as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385411/4386668). Don't forget to invalidate cache and restart in order to remove warnings in code.

Comment: Same issue. I think it has something to do with androidx and the support library conflicting but I'm not sure.

Comment: hi guys! Had the same problem when used recommended by Android Studio FragmentContainerView instead of fragment xml element in layout of main activity "no NavHostFragment found" in mainActivity and in Navigation. I returned to fragment it all works.  Gradle 4.0.1 Navigation version 2.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, as mentioned by Levi Albuquerque, this is a known bug in latest Canary Android Studio release (14). You can vote to this bug, subscribe and provide some useful information [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79667498).

**Update:**

Issue will be fixed in Android Gradle plugin 3.2.0-alpha17

Answer (score 7):

I also just have this headache as I am following Android Kotlin Fundamental tutorial at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-add-navigation/index.html#3
Here is the code that works for me

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

Apparently the tutorial has not been updated. Also in the dependency need to update the library ..

```
....    
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0"
```

I am using Android Studio 4.0.

Comment: Apologize my answer is not correct. In my case do not change the <fragment in the XML file to <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView as suggested my Android Studio. I find out I do not add the correct dependency. Make sure both the fragment and ui end with ktx, eg. fragment-ktx:$version and ui-ktx:$version. Just spent a day to solve this. Google should definitely update their Tutorial. A good side though that I learned how to solve the problem and mostly cause by dependency.

Answer (score 5):

`NavHostFragment` is not accessible?`android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`

So in your `build.gradle`, just add this two dependencies -

For Java:-

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.0"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

}
```

For Kotlin:-

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.0"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

}
```

Reference Link:-
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

Comment: Added but still don't found NavHostFragment

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, see [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8jezl4/getting_the_new_navhost_framework_to_work/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8izl2d/psa_dont_try_to_use_navigationworkmanager_libs/), the use of the Jetifier and Android X is still under refactor, In this [google i/o](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdKUm8tGogw&feature=youtu.be&t=15m6s) talk they've asked us to wait for Canary 15 which has some bug fixes.

Try to use the navigation library with the old support library for now.

**Edit:**
Android Studio 3.2 Canary 15 is available for download, everything's working fine for the navigation library. After you've finished installing clear up the clutter invalidating the cache to see if it goes fine.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I've got this enabled. I will update my question.

Comment: after some digging I've found this, apparently they've found some erros on Canary 14 and some fixes will be released in canary 15

Comment: checkout the update for Android Studio Canary 15, it's available now

Comment: I still can't use this library after update to Canary 15. It crashes after opening the app. It says that could not find `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. I thought that jetifier should handle this.

Comment: It should, did you invalidate the cache and restarted?

Comment: In some cases I had to manually remove some imports because the refactor didn't, after you invalidate the cache go into every one of your files to see if everything is ok (if there's no red lines)

Comment: Invalidating cache didn't help. How can I change import inside NavHostFragment?

Comment: See issue from @Ilosqu answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a weird Android Studio bug; and the `NavHostFragment` doesn't get resolved until:

- Invlidate Caches and Restart >> Still not resolved
- Manually add the `NavHostFragment` import `import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Under the navigation folder, there is an XML file called `nav_graph.xml`. Open it and it will prompt Gradle sync.

Project Tree

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding dependencies from [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#Set-up) helped me:

```
dependencies {
   def nav_version = "2.3.0-rc01"

  // Java language implementation
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

  // Dynamic Feature Module Support
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

  // Testing Navigation
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above answers worked.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)
```

You need to find the navigation controller like this.