# NavHostFragment not resolved (AndroidX)

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-jetpack

For some reason I always get confronted with the following error:

```
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

I was following the [Guide on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) yet the Error above occurs right after starting the App.

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
    android:name="projects.ferrari.rene.sken.ui.main.MainFragment"
    android:label="main_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_takeImageFragment"
        app:destination="@id/takeImageFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/takeImageFragment"
    android:name="projects.ferrari.rene.sken.ui.takeimage.TakeImageFragment"
    android:label="take_image_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/take_image_fragment" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    package projects.ferrari.rene.sken

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp()
            = findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
}
```

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "projects.ferrari.rene.sken"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def anko_version = "0.10.5"
    def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"

    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.github.pqpo:SmartCropper:v1.1.3@aar'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha2'
}
```

Basically I am using `Kotlin`, `AndroidX` and targeting Android P. I really can't figure out where the problem lies.

**EDIT** There might be an issue with the import. For navigation I don't import it using `AndroidX`. In [Build your first App with Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/getting-started#configure_your_gradle_file) they use `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:' + rootProject.navigationVersion` yet I could not figure out which version they were using so I read the [Architecture Component Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes#may_8_2018_paging_10_navigation_and_workmanager_alphas_room_11_androidx) where it says for AndroidX `'2.0.0-alpha1'` should be used. Unfortunately this can not be resolved.

Comment: See my question and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385411/4386668).

Answer (score 0):

For Java:

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3+"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"

}
```

For Kotlin:

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3+"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

}
```